# creating multiple pie/donut charts

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, charts

Here's the [fiddle](http://codepen.io/mcKrack/pen/MyxNez?editors=0010) i've been working on.

I'm trying to figure out how to adjust this code so I can make multiple instances of my donut chart — scaled to various sizes depending upon the size of each object's "toursCreated" (but that's secondary).

Right now I am just trying to understand how making multiples work — what are the code adjustments I need to make so I generate a pie chart for each object of data stored in the array of data.

here's the code so far...

```js
var width = 200,
    height = 150,
    radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2;

var percentageFormat = d3.format("%");

var color = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .range(["#98abc5", "#8a89a6"]);

var arc = d3.svg.arc()
    .outerRadius(radius)
    .innerRadius(40);

var labelArc = d3.svg.arc()
    .outerRadius(radius - 18)
    .innerRadius(radius - 18);

var pie = d3.layout.pie()
    .sort(null)
    .value(function(d) { return d.region; });

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");

function render (data) {

  var tots = d3.sum(data, function(d) {
    console.log(d.region);
    return d.region;
  });

  data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.percentage = d.region / tots;
    console.log(d.percentage);
  });

  var g = svg.selectAll(".arc")
      .data(pie(data))
      .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "arc");

  g.append("path")
      .attr("d", arc)
      .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.data.region); });

  g.append("text")
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" +     labelArc.centroid(d) + ")"; })
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .text(function(d) { return percentageFormat(d.data.percentage); });

  console.log(data);

  var middle = data;

  console.log(middle);
  
  var innerG = svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "innerArc")
      .append("circle")
      .attr("r", 40)
      .style("fill", "grey");

  var salesPeopleTotal = svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "sumTotal-text")
      .selectAll("text")
      .data([middle[0]])
      .enter().append("text")
      .text(tots)
      .attr('y', "5")
      .attr('x', "-10")
      .style("fill", "white");
}

var salesPeople = [
   { "region": "West",
     "toursCreated": 644,
    "totalStaff": 644,
    "activeStaff": 399,
    "inactiveStaff": 245  
   },
  { "region": "North-West",
     "toursCreated": 467,
    "totalStaff": 644,
    "activeStaff": 399,
    "inactiveStaff": 245  
   },
  { "region": "South-West",
     "toursCreated": 320,
    "totalStaff": 644,
    "activeStaff": 399,
    "inactiveStaff": 245  
   }
];

var inactive = {"name": "inactive"};
inactive.region = salesPeople[0].inactiveStaff;

var active = {"name": "active"};
active.region = salesPeople[0].activeStaff;

var myArray = [];
myArray.push(inactive);
myArray.push(active);

render(myArray);
```

Comment: Why not use a d3 wrapper/ framework like http://nvd3.org/ ?

Comment: @RhysBradbury eh because i'm trying to just understand how to do this in straight up D3. don't want to use frameworks.

Comment: Fair enough, maybe hold the d3 logic in a class, then create chart objects with the `new` operator, all with a updateChart `prototype` method. You could pass some initial options as an `object` to the charts, as you iterate over an `Array` of chart init `object`s

Comment: You would have to modify your code to work on a svg selector. currently you are appending a svg to the body, you could just work with svgs?  maybe extend JQuery?

Comment: @RhysBradbury i kinda get what you are saying in theory but am not sure how it would really translate to code. super new at this :/

Comment: @RhysBradbury I found this example but am unsure how to adapt mine to work like it...http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1305111

Comment: Okay Im going to modify your code and post it as answer. Not completely but with comments, and references to help you learn :)

Comment: @RhysBradbury bless you. thanks for helping me understand this stuff.

Comment: Have you programmed before? If so what langs? I can maybe help you with translating some concepts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe hold the d3 logic in a class, then create chart objects with the `new` operator.

Ref:
http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_object_prototypes.asp

```
//if you use the new operator on a function, you get an object.
//var chartObj = new Chart({selector: '#myChartHtmlId svg', data: {}});
function Chart(initObject) {
  //set Chart properties.
  this.width = 200;
  this.height = 200;
  this.selector = initObject.selector;
  this.d3svg = d3.select(this.selector);
  this.data = initObj.data;

  for (prop in initObject) {
    //to overwrite defaults use:
    //new Chart({width: 500, height: 500});
    this[prop] = initObject[prop];
  }
  this.render();
}

//now once you've used:
//var chartObj = new Chart();
//you can now:
//chartObj.updateData(someVarWithData);
Chart.prototype.updateData = function(data) {
  this.data = data;
  this.render();
};

Chart.prototype.render = function() {
  var svg = this.d3sv;
  //continue d3 stuff.
  //access the object data with this.data
};
```

html:
....in the body obviously..

```
<svg id="myChartHtmlId"></svg>
```

Then use:

```
var charts = [];

for (var i = 0, j = arrayOfChartInitObjects.length; i < j; i++) {
  var chartInitObj = arrayOfChartInitObjects[i];
  charts.push(new Chart(chartInitObj));
}
```

Please comment on my answer if any of this doesn't make sense/ you need further explanation.

I hope this helps.

Rhys